# Vaadin 14 project refreshing/reloading constantly

Tags: npm, netbeans, atmosphere, payara, vaadin14

I had a stable project on V 14.3 then I wanted to upgrade it to v 14.4.2 and use `pnpm` after a few dependencies changed, I can't run in debug mode anymore, it is constantly refreshing/reloading, payara log is overflowed, and creating Atmosphere-shaded threads like crazy.
I tried removing everything related to npm (package.json) or pnpm (pnpm-lock.yaml, pnpmfile etc), webpack*, removing /target, /node_modules, cleaning and rebuild in every way and I can't get rid of this error
I made a video because it is really hard to explain. [video-youtube](https://youtu.be/VX1KCni8xSI)

If I build and run it with **production** profile it works, but it is useless in dev mode
I have another project that I started directly with v14.4.2 and works perfectly, the POM's has nothing added (besides some dependencies, there are no additional plugins)

I would appreciate a hand here

Update: the problem starts when I delete the `web.xml`, I have it to force using HTTPS 8181 instead of 8080

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name></web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

Comment: Maybe related to the live-reload. Have you tried disabling it?

Comment: Added the WebInitParam but didn't work `@WebInitParam(name = "devmode.liveReload.enabled", value = "false")`

Comment: I don't have anything related to spring, no lib, no dependency

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project and BEFORE deploy it the 1st time, I removed the web.xml and run it perfectly.
the problem seems to be related to Payara 4, if the project is deployed at least one time with the web.xml mentioned and it is removed later the error appears, I tried cleaning all payara folders related to app deploys in the domain (`/applications`, `/generated` etc) and nothing works